# Convert ppt to png with apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

When I convert ppt to png using follow code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,
        IOException {
    final String PPT_TEMPLATE = "data/test.pptx";
    float scale = 1;
    XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream(PPT_TEMPLATE));

    Dimension pgsize = ppt.getPageSize();
    int width = (int) (pgsize.width * scale);
    int height = (int) (pgsize.height * scale);

    XSLFSlide slide = ppt.getSlides()[5];

    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();

    // default rendering options
    graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
    graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);

    graphics.setColor(Color.white);
    graphics.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    graphics.scale(scale, scale);

    // draw stuff
    slide.draw(graphics);

    // save the result
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/test.png"));
    try {
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", out);
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
    System.out.println("Job Done");
}
```

And I can't get the correct PNG.

first picture is a slide from ppt and second picture is the result after converting.

How can I get the correct result?

[image: slide from the ppt]
[[image: result after converting with POI][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCjug.png)

And I have confirmed that conversion chart can't display.

Comment: is the diagram a picture or an embedded Excel file ?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Apache POI? And if not, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: it's an embedded file , and I use poi-3.9.jar

Answer (score 0):

I use POI 3.10 for the same kind of purpose, and I've found out that all things embedded in the PPT file cannot be converted (including Cliparts, SmartArt, WordArt, Tables, and external Files).

Only images pasted in the file will be included in the converted file.

Answer (score 0):

TutorialPoint has a very straight forward but with little tweaking tutorial to do that [HERE.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi_ppt/apache_poi_ppt_to_image.htm) I modified to display a full pptx document on JFrame found the code below:

```
try {
        outFile = new File("pages/" + fileName); //fileName here is the name of the folder to save all the slides
        if (!outFile.exists()) {
            outFile.mkdir();
            //creating an empty presentation
            XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(is);

            //getting the dimensions and size of the slide
            Dimension pgsize = ppt.getPageSize();
            XSLFSlide[] slide = ppt.getSlides();

            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(pgsize.width, pgsize.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

            for (int i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
                Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();

                //clear the drawing area
                graphics.setPaint(Color.white);
                graphics.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, pgsize.width, pgsize.height));

                //render
                slide[i].draw(graphics);
                //creating an image file as output
                System.out.println(outFile.getName() + "/" + i + ".png");
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("pages/" + fileName + "/" + i + ".png");
                javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(img, "png", out);
                out.close();
            }
        }
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        if (outFile.exists() && outFile.isDirectory()) { //Always a good practice to check to avoid errors
            final FilenameFilter IMAGE_FILTER = new FilenameFilter() {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(final File dir, final String name) {
                    if (name.endsWith(".png")) //make sure only png are valid
                        return (true);
                    else
                        return (false);
                }
            };

            for (final File f : outFile.listFiles(IMAGE_FILTER)) {//fetch all png files within the folder
                panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(f.getAbsolutePath())));
            }
        }

        JScrollPane labelScrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel); //Wrapped in scrollpane just in case the slides are much
        add(labelScrollPane); //Add to frame or panel
```